# Why cell is deselect when I scroll down iOS (collectionview inside tableView)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview with mulitselect inside tableviewcell. When I scroll down - selected cell is deselect.
CollectionViewDelegate and DataSource contain in the cell. TableView just contain this cell. I think that, problem when TableView try to reuse cell.

```
class CategoryCollectionCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    static let identefier = "CategoryCollectionCell"

    private var items: [Value] = [] {
        didSet {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }
    
   
    private func commonInit() {
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    }
    
    func config(items: [Value]) {
        self.items = items
    }
    
   
}

extension CategoryCollectionCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        items.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CategoryCell.identefier, for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        cell.config(text: items[indexPath.row].name)
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` you have to set the cell as selected if it has been previously.

iOS resets every cell before reusing it. You have to check in your data if every cell before displaying should be selected or not.

You can either set a custom method in a custom UICollectionViewCell class or just set the cell to selected with the builtin

```
cell.isSelected = true
```